# Memcache in .NET Core by EasyCaching

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-web-api

I use this link to make the provider to Memcached [DefaultMemcachedCachingProvider](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Memcached/).

1) I download the `EasyCaching.Memcached` via Nuget

2) add config in `startup.cs` class

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEasyCaching(option =>
        {
            //use memmemcachedory cache
            option.UseMemcached(config =>
            {
                config.DBConfig.AddServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
            });
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

and the `app.UseEasyCaching();` line in `Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEasyCaching();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

3) and finally call the provider

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEasyCachingProvider _provider;

    public ValuesController(IEasyCachingProvider provider)
    {
        this._provider = provider;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _provider.RemoveAsync("demo");

            //Set Async  
            await this._provider.SetAsync("demo", "Hello world", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));


            //Get Async      
            var res = await this._provider.GetAsync<string>("demo");

            return Ok(res);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

in `exception ex` I take the error

> "Connection failed because the destination computer rejected the connection request 127.0.0.1:11111"

And I don't know how fixed it, what I did wrong? I did it by tutorial

**EDIT**

startup class

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEasyCaching(option =>
        {
            //use memmemcachedory cache
            option.UseMemcached(config =>
            {
                config.DBConfig.AddServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEasyCaching();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

My controller

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEasyCachingProvider _provider;

    public ValuesController(IEasyCachingProvider provider)
    {
        this._provider = provider;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            //Set
            _provider.Set<string>("demo", "Hello", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            //Get
            var res = _provider.Get<string>("demo");

            return Ok(res);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your Memcached server running on your local machine? If so, which port is it configured to listen on? That exception is telling you that it's not listening on port `11111`.

Comment: I didn't configure anything. In the tutorial, it's not needed.

Comment: That tutorial shows how to "handle the data of your memcached servers". It assumes you already have a [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) server.

Comment: and if I use the `Redis`, I should create the server too?
I think it saves dynamically in the cache and all work by one line. And for me a bit difficult to understand what to do in your link, because it doesn't look like tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is saying that it is trying to connect to a Memcached server on your local machine at port 11111, and it can't find it.

The EasyCaching library just helps you connect to your cache. The different providers it implements helps you connect to whatever caching database you have. In the case of [`DefaultMemcachedCachingProvider`](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Memcached/), it assumes you already have a [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) server setup.

Similarly, [`DefaultRedisCachingProvider`](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Redis/) assumes you already have a [Redis](https://redis.io/) server setup.

If you don't have any external caching server setup, then you can look at [In-Memory caching](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/In-Memory/), which will keep your cache in the memory of your application. That's easy, but it also gets wiped out when your application restarts (which may or may not be ok for you).

Or you can look at [SQLite caching](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SQLite/), which can store the cache in an SQLite file, which is just a .db file on your file system. No external caching server required.

Comment: 1 more question I add code after **NOTE** and the problem is that I take null after `_provider.Get<string>("demo");` do you know what the strange behavior? How to get from cache value?

Comment: Which cache provider are you using?

Comment: I realize Memcached, After **Edit**, I add whole my code

Comment: So did you setup a separate Memcached server now?

Comment: I didn't do anything. Just copy the code from the tutorial.

Comment: Then it won't work. `DefaultMemcachedCachingProvider` only helps you connect to a Memcached server. If you don't have a Memcached server, then you either need to set one up, or use a different provider like I described in my answer.

Comment: How to configure it because I should understand how to do that? interesting why that creates a tutorial without this main stuff. I don't understand why I need to use the server if I want to save the data in the cache.

Comment: Because that isn't what that tutorial is for. That tutorial is written to help you use EasyCaching to connect to a Memcached server that you already have.

Comment: Do you know the tutorial on how to connect to the memcached server? I don't understand what to should to do with your link?

Comment: The [link you gave](https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Memcached/) *is* the tutorial on how to *connect* to a Memcached server. What you are missing is an actual Memcached server. If you want to set one up, look at the [Memcached documentation](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Install)